# Is there an equivalent concept in iOS development to an Android product flavor?

Tags: ios, xcode

We utilize product flavors in Android to keep the same code under source control, but conditionally target the endpoints to dev/qa/production servers based on the flavor selected. For reference:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/build-system-concepts

For example, when we want to test a new endpoint in the "dev" environment we can have a file in `src/dev/res/values/endpoints.xml` that has an entry that's the XML equivalent of `urlbase = https://dev-endpoint.ourserver.com/v3/`, and build using the "dev" product flavor to build an APK pointed to our dev environment.

Is there an equivalent concept for iOS development?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.  If you select your project in the left bar, then select your Project under Project in the inner left bar, and select Info on the inner top bar, you will see a section labeled Configurations.  You can configurations here.

Then select your Target on the inner left bar and select Build Settings on the inner top bar.  Search for "preproc" in the search box.  Under the Apple LLVM - Preprocessing section, you can add custom Preprocessor Macros.  For your configurations, define something like "DEV=1", etc.

Now in your code you can say `#if DEV`, etc.

Many projects use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to talk to their back end.  You can set the [`baseURL`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.5.2/Classes/AFHTTPSessionManager.html#//api/name/baseURL) for your `AFHTTPSessionManager` subclass, or whatever, based on the defines.

Comment: There are other ways to do this, but they're all going to be based off Configurations.

Comment: So if I have 3 environments I want to support (dev, qa, and prod) I would need 6 build configurations to support debug/release for each. Right?

Comment: Yes.  But do you really need release for dev?  And qa?

Comment: Though again, you don't *have* to.  You could just build in an environment switch, for example in your Settings bundle, and just have debug/release and let end users pick and environment, and key all server requests off that setting.

Comment: Yep, I added all 6 for consistency across android/ios. In android you have a concept of a product flavor + build type, so it added all 6 for me automatically. Also we have some custom rules for release build types that are easier to debug in dev. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to work, but.. Is it possible to quickly select dev/qa/prod when running your app? like the bottom-left "Build variants" tab in Android Studio

Comment: What about changing bundle id using this principe ?