# How make different Firebase Database for Release and Debug mode(Test and Production environment) in a single iOS project/app?

Tags: ios, build, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, info.plist

Now we are working on the project that uses the Firebase Realtime Database in iOS app. Is it possible to make different Firebase Database for Release and Debug mode in single iOS app?

Project: (App with release/debug mode)

1. Debug Mode(Test Environment) - Firebase Database 1
2. Release Mode(Production Environment) - Firebase Database 2

What is the best idea to solve this Test/Production environment for Firebase Database?

Comment: I think its resolve your problem ** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360919/how-to-run-debug-app-version-on-a-debug-firebase-database **

Comment: This answer is for Android. I am asking for iOS .

Comment: Possibly helpful post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29637381/4625829)

Comment: try this https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/04/easier-configuration-for-firebase-on-web.html

Answer (score 1):

if you have use different database for DEBUG and Release Build then you have to take care Below things. I think it is not a good idea.

1) Respective .plist file should be in project.

2) Add/Remove According to Base URL.

Best Approach for Above issue.

Suppose your  BaseURL is: `https://xxxxxxx.firebaseio.com`

For Debug Build:- `https://xxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/Debug`

For Release Build:- `https://xxxxxxx.firebaseio.com`

Answer (score 1):

**Finally Solved with two simple steps**

**Step 1:** Copy *GoogleService-Info-dev.plist* and *GoogleService-Info.plist* to project workspace.

**Step 2:** Just change the *...-Info.plist* according to debug/production environment in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
/* 
* Here in  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method,
* just change the *...info.plist* file path according to the requirement
*/
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // DEBUG ENVIRONMENT
    //let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info-dev", ofType: "plist")! 

    // PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT
    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info", ofType: "plist")! 

    let options = FIROptions(contentsOfFile: filePath)
    FIRApp.configure(with: options!)

    return true
}
```

Comment: This is very useful, thanks! And it combines perfectly with `#if DEBUG` (which works in Xcode 9.4.1 (possibly earlier too) without the need of setting manually any flags).